# Build an exe file of a java project and deploy it to a ftp server

Tags: java, maven, ftp, launch4j

How can I deploy a generated exe file to a ftp server?

I'm generating the exe file with launch4j and shaded. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>console</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}-shaded.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/Addressbook.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>ch.sbb.uno.addressbook.Main</mainClass>
                            <preCp>anything</preCp>
                        </classPath>
                        <icon>src/main/resources/icon/application.ico</icon>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                            <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                            <originalFilename>Addressbook.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now how can I copy the Addressbook.exe onto a ftp server. Is this possible?

Comment: have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935433/upload-file-via-ant-ftp-task-in-maven

Comment: You mean automatically as part of the Continuous Integration? I doubt that you don't know how to use ftp ... :D

Comment: @Fildor It's not for production.. I'm learning how to use maven and I was asking me if this would be possible..

Comment: Not sure if this is it: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/ See bottom of the page, there is a link to "Deploy with FTP"